# MySQL Case when then clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, case-when

```
$this->db->select('a.diskusi_id, a.topik_id, a.diskusi_komentar, a.diskusi_file, a.pengguna_id');

$this->db->select('CASE WHEN a.pengguna_id LIKE "mhs%" THEN (select f.mahasiswa_id, f.mahasiswa_nama, f.mahasiswa_nim) WHEN a.pengguna_id LIKE "dos%" THEN (select g.dosen_id, g.dosen_nama, g.dosen_nidn)');

$this->db->where('CASE WHEN a.pengguna_id LIKE "mhs%" THEN a.pengguna_id = f.mahasiswa_id WHEN a.pengguna_id LIKE "dos%" THEN a.pengguna_id = g.dosen_id');

$query = $this->db->get('diskusi a, mahasiswa f, dosen g');
```

It gave an error:

> near from "diskusi a, mahasiswa f, dosen g"

I want to relate that if `a.pengguna_id like "mhs%"` then take data from `mahasiswa f` and if `a.pengguna_id like "dos%"` then take data from `dosen g`.
I am Using Codeigniter, but if you have some correction to SQL syntax I will try to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try profiling your model with

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

the check sql syntax with query result.

Answer (score 0):

Add `FALSE` with your select statement like this `select('a.diskusi_id, a.topik_id, a.diskusi_komentar, a.diskusi_file, a.pengguna_id', FALSE);`& check what happen. When you want to use compound select statement, you need to use FALSE as second parameter.

Comment: Thanks for replying

I have do this, with same error, syntax to use near 'FROM `diskusi` `a`, `dosen` `g`, `mahasiswa` `f` WHERE `CASE WHEN` `a`.`pengguna' at line 2

Comment: `SELECT a.diskusi_id, a.topik_id, a.diskusi_komentar, a.diskusi_file, a.pengguna_id, CASE WHEN a.pengguna_id LIKE "mhs%" THEN (select f.mahasiswa_id, f.mahasiswa_nama, f.mahasiswa_nim) WHEN a.pengguna_id LIKE "dos%" THEN (select g.dosen_id, g.dosen_nama, g.dosen_nidn) FROM `diskusi` `a`, `dosen` `g`, `mahasiswa` `f` WHERE `CASE WHEN` `a`.`pengguna_id` LIKE "mhs%" THEN (a.pengguna_id = f.mahasiswa_id) WHEN a.pengguna_id LIKE "dos%" THEN (a.pengguna_id = g.dosen_id)`

this is sql command of the error

Comment: have you added false with both select statement?

Comment: yes, I have,
I think the error is from when case clause, is there something strange?